# Matrices: Example where $AB = I \ne BA$

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, inverse, matrix-calculus

For the inverse of a matrix, we learned that to prove two matrices are inverses of each other, you must show that $AB = I = BA$. However, today in class someone claimed you only have to show either $AB = I$ or $BA = I$ to prove they are inverse. I know the commutative property doesn't apply to matrices, so can someone provide an example where $AB = I \ne BA$?

Edit: The question type goes as follows: Given matrix $A$ and matrix $B$, show whether or not the two are inverses.
-For this question, do we need to show both $AB = I$ and $BA = I$ or will one or the other suffice?

Comment: The commutative property does not apply to matrices in general however a square matrix will always commute with its inverse. Therefore if you show that either $AB=I$ or $BA=I$ then the other is true by the commutative property.

Comment: So you're asking for a counterexample to the claim made by your classmate. But, the classmate's statement is correct for square matrices, so there is no counterexample (for square matrices).

Comment: Can we consider infinite order matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from User71352:
"Since $AB=I$ then $B=B(AB)=(BA)B.$"
Since a matrix times its identity results in the same matrix, $B = BI = B(AB)$ given that $AB = I$. Since matrices follow the Associative Property, $B(AB) = (BA)B$. This tells that $B=(BA)B$. Since only the identity times the matrix will result in the same matrix, $BA$ must equal $I$.
Thus, you only need to show $AB = I$ to show the two matrices are inverses.

Comment: Where does $(BA)BB$ come from? How does the conclusion follow from $B=(BA)B$? What are the intermediate steps for? How are you using the fact that the matrices are square?

Comment: I edited my answer! Thank you! These questions helped me myself to think and understand it.